# How is this char* to short conversion happening?

Tags: c, pointers

Recently, I came across the following code:

```
char* strm;
/*there are some code here*/
short len = *(short*) strm;
strm += sizeof(len);
```

Can anyone help to find out what those line specifically mean?

Comment: You really should show us what is  assigned to `strm`.

Comment: And especially *what* don't you understand?

Comment: What is the context of the code?  What is the code you left out doing?  Knowing what's going on around this, and what type of data you're processing, will help

Answer (score 3):

This line -

```
 short len = *(short*) strm;
```

can invoke *undefined behaviour* .It breaks the [strict aliasing rule](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/StrictAliasing.html).

Comment: Not only that, it assumes the endianness of the stream matches the endianness of the processor the code is run on.

Comment: @AndrewHenle  True .Also  preferring `memcpy` will be beneficial here  as then there will be no violation of strict aliasing and it won't  matter how the char array is aligned.

Comment: `memcpy` will solve the aliasing problem but not the endianness one